# does exec mv command used with find deletes the files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, mv

I want to rename a few files in a folder with one command rather than rename them one by one.

I have a folder named `/u0x/XMLs` where there are around *500 folders*. Each of these folders has a file named `PROCESSED_ADI.XML`. I want to rename all these files to `ADI.XML`.

I tried to use `find` and `-exec mv` together:

```
XMLs]$ find . -name "*.XML" -exec mv {} ADI.XML \;
```

After the command was executed all the files have been deleted from the folders or moved from there, which I am not sure. Could someone shed some light on what went wrong and is there any way the files could be retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

> After the command was executed all the files have been deleted from the folders or moved from there, which I am not sure

You're renaming the files but the destination or rather the renamed file has a different location, It is the current location/path where you ran the `find` command.

You can use `-execdir` if your `find` supports it.

```
find . -name "*.XML" -execdir mv -v {} ADI.XML \;
```

---

Here is definition of `execdir`

```
 -execdir command {} +
              Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started  find.   As  with
              -exec,  the  {} should be quoted if find is being invoked from a shell.  This a much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolu-
              tion of the paths to the matched files.  As with the -exec action, the `+' form of -execdir will build a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given
              invocation  of  command  will  only list files that exist in the same subdirectory.  If you use this option, you must ensure that your $PATH environment variable does not
              reference `.'; otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which  you  will  run  -execdir.   The  same
              applies  to  having entries in $PATH which are empty or which are not absolute directory names.  If any invocation with the `+' form returns a non-zero value as exit sta-
              tus, then find returns a non-zero exit status.  If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be run  at  all.
              The result of the action depends on whether the + or the ; variant is being used; -execdir command {} + always returns true, while -execdir command {} ; returns true only
              if command returns 0.
```

---

### Here is a bit of demo about what/why did your files got removed deleted.

Let's create a dummy directories and file anywhere but here we will create them in `/tmp`

```
cd  /tmp
```

---

Let's create the directories and files.

```
mkdir -p u0x/XMLs/folder_{1..10} && touch u0x/XMLs/folder_{1..10}/PROCESSED_ADI.XML
```

---

Now check what was created inside those directories, using the `tree` command.

```
tree u0x/
```

---

Output

```
u0x/
└── XMLs
    ├── folder_1
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_10
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_2
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_3
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_4
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_5
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_6
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_7
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    ├── folder_8
    │   └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML
    └── folder_9
        └── PROCESSED_ADI.XML

11 directories, 10 files
```

---

Now we execute your `find` command, but with the `-v` flag/option.

```
find u0x/ -name "*.XML" -exec mv -v {} ADI.XML \;
```

---

Output

```
renamed './XMLs/folder_2/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_9/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_7/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_10/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_6/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_3/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_8/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_1/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_4/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
renamed './XMLs/folder_5/PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -> 'ADI.XML'
```

---

Now check what happened to the files using the `tree` command.

```
tree u0x/
```

---

Output

```
u0x/
├── ADI.XML
└── XMLs
    ├── folder_1
    ├── folder_10
    ├── folder_2
    ├── folder_3
    ├── folder_4
    ├── folder_5
    ├── folder_6
    ├── folder_7
    ├── folder_8
    └── folder_9

11 directories, 1 file
```

---

Now If you take a good look at the above output from `tree` *all* of the `PROCESSED_ADI.XML` are gone from it's location/folder but there is one `ADI.XML` inside the parent directory/folder `u0x`
Like what was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951355/does-exec-mv-command-used-with-find-deletes-the-files/69951465#comment123653834_69951465) by [@Gordon Davidson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) *All* the xml (as long as the file ends in *.xml*) files has been moved in one location and it was overwritten again and again so now you have only one file named. `ADI.XML`

---

Using `-execdir` will have the expected output you're looking for.

---

The output of the `tree` command if `-execdir` was used, should be:

```
tree u0x/

u0x/
└── XMLs
    ├── folder_1
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_10
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_2
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_3
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_4
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_5
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_6
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_7
    │   └── ADI.XML
    ├── folder_8
    │   └── ADI.XML
    └── folder_9
        └── ADI.XML

11 directories, 10 files
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The issue here is, after I executed the command find . -name "*.XML" -exec mv {} ADI.XML \; from /u0x/Xmls/, the files I wanted to rename have been gone from the subfolders.  

so now when I run the command
find . -name "*.XML" -execdir mv -v {} ADI.XML \;
it returns nothing as no files are found by the "find  . -name "*.XML"

Comment: @SaNu, yes because it has been moved from it's location/path to the current location/path where you ran the `find` command.

Comment: @SaNu Unfortunately, I think all but one of them have been deleted. It tried to move them all to the same place, but each one it moved replaced the previous one (deleting it). This is why I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -n` for any sort of bulk/automated move/rename operation. Do you have a backup?

Comment: @ Gordon Davisson Unfortunately I don't have a backup and I think what you said is exactly happened.

Comment: As I checked I dont have any .XML files in that  folder were the find command was execcuted, which looks like all the files found by the find command from subfloders have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **do not use a wildcard**. Even with `-execdir`, you're creating a circumstance where all `.XML` files in a directory will be overwritten with the last match in that directory.

```
find . -type f -name 'PROCESSED_ADI.XML' -exec sh -c 'for i do echo mv "${i}" "$(dirname "$i")/ADI.XML"; done' _ {} +
```

Run this, as a dry run. If it looks ok, remove `echo`.